# how to retrieve a list of object from a jlist

Tags: object, jlist, multi-select

i have a Jlist filled with a hashmap of -Integer,"Obra"- objects, and i have a method that receive a list of obras, i'm trying to get all the selectd obras in that Jlist and trying to pass as parameter to my method, but i keep getting a error that the types mismatch

here's my code

```
public class Emprestimo {
private Usuario u;
private Calendar dataRealizacao;
private double total = 0;

public Emprestimo(Usuario u){
    this.u = u;
    dataRealizacao = Calendar.getInstance();
}

public void realizaEmprestimo(Obra... o){
    try{...do stuff


anotherclass
emp = new Emprestimo(user);
emp.realizaEmprestimo(JlistObra.getSelectedValuesList()); // here's where i get my error
```

i have tried to do a cast like this

```
(emp.realizaEmprestimo((Obra)JlistObra.getSelectedValuesList());
```

and this

```
(emp.realizaEmprestimo((Obra[])JlistObra.getSelectedValuesList());
```

but it doesn't work

and i have done:

```
emp.realizaEmprestimo((Obra) JlistObra.getSelectedValue());
```

which works, but with just one select element in my Jlist

Answer (score 0):

i made it work, not the best way possible, but a solutaion is a solution:

```
int[] indices = JlistObra.getSelectedIndices();

        for (int i : indices){
            emp.realizaEmprestimo((Obra)JlistObra.getModel().getElementAt(i));
        }
```